# How do I create these colored bars/boxes/square rounded boxes by themselves that seems to be in its own table in R or python or even exel?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, format, kable

[image: Player and EPA]

How do I create these colored bars/boxes/square rounded boxes by themselves that seems to be in a table in R or python or even excel? I want to create this exact table from scratch and with fixed numbers is fine for now.

```
Player <- c('T.Lawrence', 'D.Carr')
Plays <- c(35,62)
EPA_play <- c(0.32, -0.28)
Total_EPA <- c(11.3, -17.2)

df <- data.frame(Player,Plays,EPA_play,Total_EPA)
df
kable(df)
```

This is the output but maybe in a quarto would be nice...?

```
|Player     | Plays| EPA_play| Total_EPA|
|:----------|-----:|--------:|---------:|
|T.Lawrence |    35|     0.32|      11.3|
|D.Carr     |    62|    -0.28|     -17.2|
```

I just want the display to look the same as the PICTURE ABOVE with the bars being displayed in the chart. How do I get the bars to display within the table?

Comment: I do NOT need/want the images of the team's logos within the table/dataframe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @comtuner. Lots of people here will be willing to help, but standard practice here is to ask Qs that include data sufficient to create a reproducible example. Can you provide a `dput()` of your data? What code have you attempted? It may be that `kable()` will be all you create the table you're after.

Comment: dput(df)
structure(list(Player = c("T.Lawrence", "D.Carr"), Plays = c(35, 
62), EPA_play = c(0.32, -0.28), Total_EPA = c(11.3, -17.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

Comment: @comtuner Kindly put the output of `dput()`directly on the post by editing it. So that no-one needs to go to the comments for it